# How to skip the first line of a CSV file while reading it in SystemVerilog?

Tags: csv, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to read a CSV file in SystemVerilog and parse them and assign the values to an associative array. I want to skip the first line of the CSV file while reading it. I am using the following task to read the file into SystemVerilog:

```
while (!$feof(file)) begin
    $fscanf(file, "%s\n", line);

    for (i = 0; i < line.len(); i++) begin
        if (line[i] == ",") begin
        break;
        end
    end

    if (i != line.len()) begin
        register_name = line.substr(0, i-1);
        exp_value = line.substr(i + 1, line.len() - 1);
    end else begin
        $display("Error: The line format is not readable. Line: %s. Please check it", line);
    end

    if (exp_value.len() > 0) begin
        $sscanf(exp_value, "%h", value);
    end else begin
        $display("Error: Value is not able to be read. Line: %s, Value: %h. Please check it", line, exp_value);
    end

    Temp_Arr.name = register_name;
    Temp_Arr.value = value;

    RegData[register_name] = Temp_Arr;
        
end
```

I also tried to use the `$fscanf` line before the `while` loop hoping it would skip the first line, but it is not working.

The contents of the input file are like this:

```
Register Name,Expected Value
Reg_1,0abd4
Reg_2,4eec3
...
```

I want to skip the header line while parsing the file. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not need to format the header line like you do for the following lines, use `$fgets` instead of `$fscanf` before the `while` loop:

```
$fgets(line, file);
while (!$feof(file)) begin
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.3.4.2 *Reading a line at a time* :

> One line can be read from a file using `$fgets`.

Regarding your problem:

> I also tried to use the `$fscanf` line before the `while` loop hoping it would skip the first line

It does not work because the format string (`"%s\n"`) does not match the header line.